# How to count occurrences in VERY LARGE dataset with PHP

Tags: php, performance, optimization, memory-management, bigdata

Let's say I want to keep track of the number of times a word occurs...

```
//Update the totals
foreach($arrayOfWords as $word) {
    $totals[$word] = $totals[$word] + 1;
}
```

Now, imagine, that this little block of code is called HUNDREDS of times, each times with HUNDREDS OF THOUSANDS of NEW words in $arrayWords each time, leading to millions of entries inside of the associate array $totals.  Despite the simplicity of the operation (adding 1 to the existing value), PHP slows down significantly as we approach millions of entries.

Can you think of a better way to count occurrences (preferably without using a database)?

Comment: [array_count_values()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) is the built-in function that will do this for you.... but there isn't going to be a fast solution when you're working with HUNDREDS OF THOUSANDS of words without using a database.... you're going to run out of memory first

Comment: Maybe take a look at [generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.php)

Comment: @quickshiftin - out of interest, how would you use a generator to do this?

Comment: @MarkBaker it seems I misunderstood the question, at first; sorry for the hasty comment.

Comment: @quickshiftin Damn :( I was currently looking into generators.. nice to learn about them though, thanks anyways :)

Comment: See my answer, there may be more optimizations, but this is a quick and easy one and should save some cycles for sure!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to speed it up

```
//Update the totals
foreach($arrayOfWords as $word) {
    $totals[$word]++;
}
```

No need to search for the same key within the hash twice just to increment its value.

Also, (just a note) I don't see how the length of `$totals` could ever exceed the length of `$arrayOfWords`, unless you're adding words to `$totals` somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I'll try that speed boost :)

Comment: $totals will keep growing because else where in code, we'll keep getting a new batch of $arrayOfWords, and then call that little foreach loop again

Comment: Maybe in that case if you show us more code we could help improve it. Seems you are incrementing every value each time you get a new batch of words then yes? So if you start with one word say 'hi', then add another word, 'bye', your `$totals` array would be `['hi' => 2, 'bye' => 1]`; is that the idea?

Comment: if batch1 contains 'hi' (as well as hundreds of thousands of other words), and batch2 also contains 'hi' (as well as a different set of hundreds of thousands of words), then $totals would be ['hi' => 2, ..(tons of other words with a value of 1)]

Answer (score 2):

Combining the suggestions of [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726337/how-to-count-occurrences-in-very-large-dataset-with-php#comment55221913_33726337) and [quickshiftin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33726475), the following code should be quite a bit faster if the input word list contains many repeated words:

```
$counts = array_count_values( $words );
foreach( $counts as $word => $count ) {
    $totals[$word] += $count;
}
```

That said, in any case, PHP is probably not the optimal tool for this kind of massive data processing.  However, without knowing more about *why* you want to do this, it's hard to suggest specific alternatives.

Comment: Took me a second to see what you're doing there, but yeah, that looks like it should be faster if the `$words` array is a list of non-unique values. Upvote from me :)

Comment: You don't need the loop at all: `$totals = array_count_values( $words );` should be all you need

Comment: @MarkBaker: The OP says they want to be able to call this code repeatedly, with different `$words`, and to accumulate the total sum of the word counts into `$totals`. Your version would wipe away any earlier counts already in `$totals`.